# Rails 4 + PostgreSQL 9.6 hstore, can't execute “CREATE EXTENSION hstore”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, hstore

I need to get Hstore to work for Rails application that I'm working on. I'm running Linux Mint 18 and psql (9.6.1, server 9.5.5) and postgresql-contrib 9.6. As far as I'm aware, hstore should be installed and enabled by installing the `postgresql-contrib`. However when I load the psql console and do `\dx` I don't see the Htop showing in the "installed extensions". When I run

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the server you're running is 9.5, why are you installing postgres-contrib 9.6?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

```
  sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.*
```

where 9.* is your postgres version,
or simply reinstall `pg` gem.